# How to set up Environment java variable in Ubuntu bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

I am trying to set up Java in my new laptop. I have installed java jdk and I am trying to set up the environment variable now, But I am really confused between the file .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile. I understand the concept behind login and non login shells, but when I wrote the JAVA_HOME, PATH variable in .bash_profile I needed to manually run the command

> . .bash_profile

It did not get executed at the start when I restarted the computer to make it run as .bash_profile is supposed to be called by login shells. Can anyone explain to me what is the reason behind .bash_profile not being called up?

Since .bash_profile was not being called, I decide to type the PATH, JAVA_HOME variable to the file .bashrc, While this is working is this the right way to set up environment variables?

Comment: Place it in `.profile` or `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: @konsolebox When placed inside `.bashrc` it would be executed each time a bash is started. Whilst this does not break anything it is not required.

Comment: @arkascha That is what my understanding is? could you please explain to me what .bash_profile is not working the way it is supposed to?

Comment: Whether `.bash_profile` is executed depends on the setup of your system, or the setup of Ubuntu in this case. You could check under the routines in `/etc`, most likely `/etc/profile`... note that there is no buildin magic evaluating these files. It is all done in the scripts/routines you find in `/etc`.

Comment: @arkascha What do you mean not required?

Comment: @arkascha That's true, My scripting knowledge is not so good, I did check out the code of /etc/profile but I am not sure what I am supposed to change.

Comment: I just recommended `.bashrc` just in case `.profile` wouldn't work. But I actually meant about .profile: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it

Comment: @konsolebox Well, setting an environment variable is required only once. It is inherited by spawned shells. It wastes performance if it is defined again and again.

Comment: @arkascha True for `.bashrc`.

Comment: @konsolebox Sorry, that comment of yours is wrong: `.bash_profile` and `.profile` serve the same purpose. `.bashrc` is different.

Comment: @arkascha What I mean is true that `.bashrc` would get executed everytime bash is called (interactively), but I first recommended `.profile`.

Comment: @arkascha .profile seems to have worked, any idea why .bash_profile was not working?

Comment: Told you above: this depends on the routines defined in the login defintion under `/etc`. This is a question of the setup your distribution provides. I have very little experience with Ubuntu since I use other distrobutions, sorry.